# Flyway version (3.0 -> 4.2.0) updated checksums but marks migrations as Future state

Tags: flyway

I am currently working to get Flyway 3.0 version up to 4.2.0 and am having some trouble going from 3.0 -> 4.2.0. So far I've pulled in the 4.2.0 dependency and updated the renamed config fields.

When looking through the Flyway migration docs & issues it seemed that when a user runs flyway on version 4.2.0 that the checksums update automatically. I assumed that meant `flyway migrate` or any relevant commands would trigger this update, via the documentation:

> Flyway 4.0 now ignores line endings when calculating checksums and all existing checksums in your metadata table will be **automatically adjusted on first run** to be compatible with this new algorithm.

However, the checksums did not update when running flyway migrate. As a work around, I found the helpful `repair` command which amends the migration checksum values from the old version to the new version and ran that:

```
flyway repair -user=user -password=password -url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db -table=db_migrations
Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_migrations (MySQL 5.6)
Repair of failed migration in metadata table `db_migrations`.`schema_version` not necessary. No failed migration detected.
Successfully repaired metadata table `db_migrations`.`schema_version` (execution time 00:00.005s).
Manual cleanup of the remaining effects the failed migration may still be required.
Database: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_migrations (MySQL 5.6)
Repair of failed migration in metadata table `db_migrations`.`schema_version` not necessary. No failed migration detected.
Successfully repaired metadata table `db_migrations`.`schema_version` (execution time 00:00.004s).
Manual cleanup of the remaining effects the failed migration may still be required.
[1]-  Done                    flyway repair -user=user -password=password -url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db -table=db_migrations
[2]+  Done                    flyway repair -user=user -password=password -url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db -table=db_migrations
```

The checksums updated but when I ran `flyway info` it shows that all the previous migrations are now marked `future`. Looking through the documentation future is defined:

> These are migrations that were performed by a newer deployment of the application that are not yet available in this version. For example: we have migrations available on the classpath up to version 3.0. The schema history table indicates that a migration to version 4.0 (unknown to us) has already been applied.

However when checking the version I get the correct one:

> flyway -v
>       Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

TLDR: Ran the `repair` command to update migration checksums and now flyway tells me the migrations have a checksum from a future version. Checked command line flyway and application flyway version and they are both at 4.2.0. Unsure how to debug / proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Found one of the maintainers comments on another question defining future further

> future -> executed, no longer found in configured locations, newer than the newest found script

So possibly the cmd line flyway can't locate the migration scripts it sees in the db?